In the Italian exam CELI, what does E mean?
The full name is "Certificato di Conoscenza della Lingua Italiana". But what is "E" in the acronym?
For instance, TOEFL = test of English as foreign language. But in case of CELI it seems that it takes 2 first letters from  "CErtificato"  + Lingua  + Italiana = CELI?

That happens even in English: radar (radio detection and ranging), lidar (light detection and ranging), and loran (*long-range navigation) are few examples.

The usual definition of acronym is a word formed from the initial letters or groups of letters of words in a set phrase or series of words. group of letters can also mean the first two letters in a word. Which letters or groups of letters are used in an acronym is not set in stone. There could be many reasons for the acronym choice, for example to avoid confusion with other acronyms.
